# Wordpress custom REST API

Tags: php, wordpress, rest

I have been working on a Wordpress plugin and I come from a background where I usually write my own REST endpoints (Rails etc). My question is, how do I from a WP plugin create rest url endpoints?

E.g.:

/myplugin/save-tutorial (POST takes JSON and returns JSON)
/myplugin/get-tutorial?id= (GET returns JSON)

How do I create such REST endpoints? I have looked at admin-ajax.php and that seems about right, but still pretty messy. It seems like a simple problem though. I want to process the responses in my-plugin.php.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not yet implemented by me, but dig this plugin http://wordpress.org/plugins/json-rest-api/ might be its helpful for you, to create endpoints for the API.

Comment: Yes but if I understand the description of the plugin correctly, isn't that plugin just creating JSON endpoints for the regular pages? So you can use a custom frontend for WP?

Comment: I'd research [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=rest+endpoint)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `add_rewrite_endpoint()` for this purposes. This function creates extra rewrite rules for each of the matching places specified by the provided bitmask. For example: 
`add_rewrite_endpoint( 'json', EP_PERMALINK | EP_PAGES );`

will add a new rewrite rule ending with `json(/(.*))?/?$` for every permastruct
that describes a permalink (post) or page. This is rewritten to `json=$match`
where $match is the part of the URL matched by the endpoint regex (e.g. `foo` in
`<permalink>/json/foo/`).

You can also read this guide
https://make.wordpress.org/plugins/2012/06/07/rewrite-endpoints-api/

Comment: I solved this with instead of using actual endpoints for my Backbone.js app, I added some `actions` in Wordpress, and then used their JSON-RPC api for it. Here is a link: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
register_rest_route ( string $namespace, string $route, array $args = array(), bool $override = false )
```

function to register a rest api in wordpress.

you can look in to this sample snippet http://wiki.workassis.com/wordpress-create-rest-api/